# Dekker's Algorithm not working fine for three processes

Tags: java, algorithm, concurrency

I've tried to modify the famous '[Dekker's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dekker%27s_algorithm)', so you can use it with three processes at the same time. Here's my code:

```
package DekkersAlgorithm;

class DekkerAlg {
    /* Iterations done by each Thread */
    static final int iterations = 2000000;
    /* Shared variable */
    static volatile int sharedInteger = 0;
    /* P Thread for critical section */
    static volatile boolean wantp = false;
    /* Q Thread for critical section */  
    static volatile boolean wantq = false;
    /* Z Thread for critical section */ 
    static volatile boolean wantz = false;
    /* Thread turn */
    static volatile int turn = 1;

class P extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        for (int i=0; i<iterations; ++i) {
            /* No critical section */
            wantp = true;
            while (wantq || wantz) {
                if (turn == 2) {
                    wantp = false;
                    while (turn == 2)
                        Thread.yield();
                    wantp = true;
                }
            }

            /* Critical section */
            ++sharedInteger;
            /* End critical section */

            turn = 2;
            wantp = false;
        }
    }
}

class Q extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        for (int i=0; i<iterations; ++i) {
            /* No critical section */
            wantq = true;
            while (wantp || wantz) {
                if (turn == 1) {
                    wantq = false;
                    while (turn == 1)
                        Thread.yield();
                    wantq = true;
                }
            }

            /* Critical section */
            --sharedInteger;
            /* End critical section */

            turn = 1;
            wantq = false;
        }
    }
}

class Z extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        for (int i=0; i<iterations; ++i) {
            /* No critical section */
            wantz = true;
            while (wantp || wantq) {
                if (turn == 3) {
                    wantz = false;
                    while (turn == 3)
                        Thread.yield();
                    wantz = true;
                }
            }

            /* Critical section */
            ++sharedInteger;
            /* End critical section */

            turn = 3;
            wantz = false;
        }
    }
}

DekkerAlg() {
    Thread p = new P();
    Thread q = new Q();
    Thread z = new Z();
    p.start();
    q.start();
    z.start();

    try {
        p.join();
        q.join();
        z.join();
        System.out.println("The value of the sharedInteger is " + sharedInteger);
        System.out.println("It should be different from 0.");
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {}
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new DekkerAlg();
  }
}
```

It's working fine for low iterations, but when I set this variable to 500(+), the program sometimes can't finish. I think that a `livelock` is happening between the two last `Threads`, but I need a clue about how to solve it.

Can you help me please?

Comment: Can you explain how you think this livelock is happening?

Comment: First Thread (Q for example) finishes, so now it's the turn of Thread Z or P. The first one (let's imagine that it's P) that takes the lead, will make one iteration (meanwhile the other Thread keeps into the loop). Now, Thread Z should exit from the loop, BUT, what happens if Thread P reaches the line where it sets his boolean to true again before Thread Z can exit from the loop? There will be a chance where both would understand that they must keep into the loop until the other one finishes his critical section, and nothing will happen. Maybe I'm wrong? @ScottHunter

Comment: I had a simpler scenario (or at least description): Z is in its CS, P & Q wish to enter theirs, setting `wantp` and `wantq`, respectively, to true.  Then Z exits, setting `turn` to 3, preventing either of P or Q from changing either of `wantp` or `wantq`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you have extended `turn` properly.  In Dekker, it meant *who gets to enter their CS if both want to*; here it seems to mean *who has to wait if someone else want to enter their CS*.  For 2 processes, those are direct opposites; for 3, not so much.

One approach would be to have a list of the processes, specifying who has to wait for whom if there is contention for the CS.  This way, if P & Q want to enter, and Z just exited, Z would be moved to the end of the list, so you'd have a way to choose between P & Q.  (If you could represent this "list" in a way that modifications to it could be atomic, which is feasible since there are only 6 different patterns to represent, all the better!)

Comment: Great idea! Thank you man, I will take a rest and I will try this tomorrow :)